# Django 1.4 and CONN_MAX_AGE

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, graphite

I have graphite-web with apache, mod_wsgi and Django 1.4. This construction makes a pool of connections to MySQL, which open and hanging. In the version Django 1.6 added option CONN_MAX_AGE, that can set the lifetime of connections. Is there such a possibility in 1.4?

Upgrade to 1.6 is not possible, set the timeout in Mysql not considered.

Comment: If you can't update the framework version and can't modify the database settings, what would you want to do? You could patch and create your own back-end to implement `CONN_MAX_AGE` in Django 1.4 but it is... quite dirty.

Comment: I want to dispose of persistent connections to the database.